# Shortcut syntax to get property of potentially undefined object

Tags: typescript

I have a `category` that can be `undefined`. I declare a variable which contains its name. Its type is hence `string | undefined`.

I can declare it like this :

```
let categoryName = undefined;
if(category) {
  categoryName = category.name;
}
```

But is there a shortcut syntax? I am looking for something like :

```
const categoryName = category?.name
```

Answer (score 2):

No, [nullish coalesce is a Stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing), and TypeScript's design principles dictate that they only implement Stage 3 proposals. So until that proposal (or something equivalent) advances, TypeScript won't have that syntax shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no. However, the `?.` operator you want is in the [optional-chaining proposal](https://github.com/TC39/proposal-optional-chaining) and is currently in stage 1. Typescript will only begin to implement new proposals when they are deemed stable enough which the typescript team have stated to be [stage 3 or onwards](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19044).

You may use the `&&` operator which returns the first argument if it is 'falsy' or else it returns the second argument

```
category && category.name
```

However this isn't great for more complicated nested cases such as

```
category && category.parentCategory && category.parentCategory.name
```

which would be much cleaner as

```
category?.parentCategory?.name
```

You may use the `!` operator to assert that a variable is not `undefined` or `null` but this is generally not what you want as you are overriding the type checker entirely

```
category!.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&&` operator. The `&&` operator will return the second operand if the first one is truthy. In this case that means if `category` is not `undefined` (ie truthy) it will return the value of the second expression. If `category` is `undefined` it is falsy and thus the value of the first operand is returned (ie undefined)

```
let categoryName: string | undefined;
declare let category :{ name: string} | undefined
categoryName = category && category.name;
```

If you just want to ignore the typescript error and are reasonably sure the value can't be undefined you can use the not null assertion operator

```
categoryName = category!.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
const categoryName = !isUndefined(category)?.name
```

where isUndefined is imported from

```
import { isUndefined } from 'util';
```

Comment: And what is `util`?